# Bad file Descriptor boost dll

Tags: c++, boost

#### main.cpp

```
#include <boost/dll.hpp> 
#include <iostream>
# include "abstract.h"

using namespace boost::dll;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


     boost::filesystem::path lib_path("/home/deven/Music/dllimport");    
    boost::shared_ptr<my_api_interface> plugin;   
    std::cout << "Loading the plugin" << std::endl;

    plugin = import<my_api_interface>(          
        lib_path / "libctest.so.1.0",                     
        "plugin",                                       
        load_mode::append_decorations              
    );

    plugin->cal(10,20);
}
```

#### abstract.h

```
# ifndef ABSTRACT_H
# define ABSTRACT_H
class   my_api_interface
{

    public:
     my_api_interface();

    virtual void cal(int a ,int b) = 0;

    ~my_api_interface();

};
# endif
```

#### lib.h

```
# include "abstract.h"
# include <boost/dll.hpp>
# ifndef LIB_H
# define LIB_H

namespace my_name
{
    class actual_api : public my_api_interface
    {
        public:
        actual_api();
        void cal(int ,int ) ;
        ~actual_api();
    };

    extern "C" BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT actual_api plugin;
    actual_api plugin;
}
# endif
```

#### lib.cpp

```
# include "lib.h"
# include <iostream>

using std::endl;

using std::cout;
void my_name::actual_api:: cal(int a,int b)
{
    cout << a+ b << endl;
}
```

getting a the error terminate called after throwing an instance of  undefined symbol: _ZN7my_name10actual_apiD1Ev): Bad file descriptor
Aborted (core dumped)
I have create .so in linux using -fpic and then loading the .so using boost.dll. I am getting this bad fd error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You need to implement all your methods

Comment: it is still not working

Comment: Please edit your question to show your updated code and any new error messages